# How to save hardware-related config from an Ubuntu install

Tags: drivers, system-installation, hibernate

I have just taken delivery of a laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed (from Entroware). I would like to back up enough system settings information so that I could do a fresh install one day if I need to, for example if the disk fails, and have all the hardware Just Work.

I'm thinking things like the X config and any special kernel modules or config to drive the wifi, get hibernation working, etc. The things I might typically have to tinker with to get a new Linux install working on a laptop.

I've taken copies of the following - do I need anything else?

- Tarball of /etc
- Output of lsmod, lsusb, dmesg, uname -a, dpkg --get-selections

I'm not bothered about lists of software installed or user data; I'm comfortable with backing up what I need there.

Comment: I don't know Entroware but most vendors of pre-installed Ubuntu tend to choose hardware already supported with Nvidia graphics being the only exception. Drivers for Nvidia are easy to install though. System76 has a PPA providing drivers and tweaks for their models (also includes Nvidia drivers) so there's never the need to do what you want.

Comment: I maintain a script of Installation and configuration routines.  Upon reinstalling the OS, I pull out my handy-dandy script, and away I go.....